# How can we use LaTeX macros within a Markdown environment?

Tags: macros, markdown

I write comprehensive documentation in LaTeX and use the [`markdown`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/markdown) package for quick writing and to get easily readable source code.

Markdown simplifies writing. But how can I still use LaTeX macros within Markdown text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tightLists=false]{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
# Workflows
Two options:

- Embedding Markdown in \LaTeX 
- Using Pandoc with \LaTeX\ inside Markdown
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: LaTeX output]

I did not yet find a way in the [markdown manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf) or in `markdown.lua` to disable rendering the backslash and to let macros be expanded. Do you know a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the option `hybrid=true`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tightLists=false,hybrid=true]{markdown}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
# Workflows
Two options:

- Embedding Markdown in \LaTeX
- Using Pandoc with \LaTeX\ inside Markdown
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See page 10 in the manual:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks obvious now, I just did not find this in the manual, neither by browsing nor by keyword search for "macro" or "backslash" with that phrasing in the manual.